# Cryovac tenderloin left in trunk of my car

Tags: food-safety, meat

I unintentionally left a whole cryovac tenderloin roast in the trunk of my car for 36 hours, big mistake I know!  The temperature range during that time was between 25 - 55 degress, mostly in the 35 - 45 degree range. Is it safe to eat?

Comment: Most likely not

Comment: Celsius or Fahrenheit?